# how to set height of textbox in tree view from xml in openerp?

Tags: xml-parsing, odoo

```
  <record id="view_tr_mail_template_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">view_tr_mail_template_tree</field>
        <field name="model">tr.mail.template</field>
        <field name="type">tree</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">    
            <tree string="Mail template">
                 <field name="category" select="1" />    
                 <field name="tr_lang" select="1" />
                 <field name="mail_desc" height="250"/>         
            </tree>
        </field>
  </record>
```

the above code shows tree view.my requirement is ,if i av a text of 50 to 80 lines in form view,in tree view the whole text as to be concatenated to 3 or 4 lines and display. giving height="250" in tree view does not work.....

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question, but in case someone's looking for the answer: here's what you'll have to do.

**Step 1.** Create the directory structure `static/src/css` in your module's root directory and create a new css file in that directory (eg. `my_styles.css`)

**Step 2.** Create the following style definitions in the css file:

```
.text_high {
    height: 250px;
}

.text_high textarea {
    height: 100%;
}
```

..and adjust the height to your needs. In my case I found out that 45px was perfect for me (~2 rows).

**Step 3.** Add this in your `__openerp__.py`:

```
"css": ["static/src/css/my_styles.css"],
```

**Step 4.** Add the class attribute to your text field tag like this:

```
<field name="mail_desc" class="text_high"/>
```

**Step 5.** Update your module and you're all set.